# MySQL get the 2 last of each version in one table

Tags: mysql

I would like to retrieve the 2 last version of a process:

```
| id | name  | version | souce_id |
| 1  | test1 | 1.00    | 0        |
| 2  | test1 | 1.01    | 1        |
| 3  | test1 | 1.02    | 1        |
| 4  | test1 | 1.03    | 1        |
| 5  | test2 | 1.00    | 0        |
| 6  | test2 | 1.01    | 4        |
| 7  | test2 | 1.02    | 4        |
| 8  | test3 | 1.00    | 0        |
```

and the expected result would be:

```
| id | name  | version | souce_id |
| 3  | test1 | 1.02    | 1        |
| 4  | test1 | 1.03    | 1        |
| 6  | test2 | 1.01    | 4        |
| 7  | test2 | 1.02    | 4        |
| 8  | test3 | 1.00    | 0        |
```

I have written this query but I don't like it... and I cannot include it in as a subquery in a `WHERE id IN (...)`.

`SELECT (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(id ORDER BY process_version DESC), ',', 2) FROM process WHERE process_name = parent.process_name) AS ids FROM process AS parent WHERE 1 GROUP BY process_name`

Comment: It seem you need last 5 records. Am i right ?

Comment: @mr.developer no

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks Strawberry!
With just a small correction I have my request (yours was giving the 2 1st versions):

```
SELECT `x`.*, `y`.`id`
  FROM `my_table` AS `x`
  JOIN `my_table` AS `y`
    ON `y`.`name` = `x`.`name`
    AND `y`.`id` >= `x`.`id`
GROUP BY `x`.`id`
HAVING COUNT(*) <=2  
ORDER BY `x`.`name` ASC, `x`.`version` ASC
```

Comment: This solution is flawed. Also, if you don't include @ in the addressee's name, then they won't see the comment (just like I didn't - until just now).

Answer (score 0):

E.g.

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM my_table x
  JOIN my_table y
    ON y.name = x.name
   AND y.id <= x.id
 GROUP
    BY x.id
 HAVING COUNT(*) <=2;
```